# Align text in gridcolumn (extjs 4.2.1)

Tags: extjs

i have a treepanel i create with a store(of nodes) and with .reconfigure(store).
In the end i get a table with 2 td's in a row(name/value).
How can i change 2nd td's(values) text-align after with extjs(NOT raw dom & .style and NOT with css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for the alignment of the header of the column please use  the *align* property.Please check the following link from the docs [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-align).

If you are asking for the alignment of the data in the column you can always use the *renderer* function to return the html with class something like the below

```
  renderer : function(value, record){
        return Ext.String.format('<div class="tree-font">{0}</div>', value);
    }
```

You can define the class in your css or you can directly write the *style* property in the div like below

```
renderer : function(value, record){
            return Ext.String.format('<div style="margin-left:5px;">{0}</div>', value);
        }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: somebody at work gave me something very close to this, so i guess it is the right answer, even though i already have one :) thanks